# Find coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x+2x^2+3x^3+.....+nx^n)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

Find coefficient of  $x^n$ in

$(1+x+2x^2+3x^3+.....+nx^n)^2$

My attempt:Let $S=1+x+2x^2+3x^3+...+nx^n$

$xS=x+x^2+2x^3+3x^4+...+nx^{n+1}$

$(1-x)S=1+x+x^2+x^3+....+x^n-nx^{n+1}-x=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}-nx^{n+1}-x$

$S=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{1-x+x^2}{(1-x)^2}$. (Ignoring terms which have powers of x greater than $x^n$)

So one can say that

coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x+2x^2+3x^3+.....+nx^n)^2$

=coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1-x+x^2)^2(1-x)^{-4}$

Is there a shorter way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such coefficient is clearly
$$ 2n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k(n-k) = \frac{n(n^2+11)}{6}.$$

Comment: Your definition of "clearly" is not very clear for me.  :-/

Comment: What is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $$(a_0+a_1 x +\ldots + a_n x^n)(a_0+a_1 x +\ldots + a_n x^n)$$ ? It is, clearly, $a_0 a_n + a_1 a_{n-1} +\ldots $.

Comment: The answer obtained is correct but I agree with what Simple Art says

Comment: I have just explained my point.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we just can't see this equality very well.  I'm sure we'll be saying "doh!" by the end, but we'd like more explanation atm.

Comment: @SimpleArt: This solution essentially asks, what are the different $x^n$ terms in the product, and then collects them all.  There is the $x^0$ term from the first polynomial times the $x^n$ term from the second, the $x^1$ term from the first times the $x^{n-1}$ term from the second, the $x^2$ term from the first times the $x^{n-2}$ term from the second, etc., until the $x^n$ term from the first times the $x^0$ term from the second.  The summation simply adds them up.

Comment: @BrianTung I knew I'd be saying "doh!" at the end.  :D

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use
$$ (f(x)g(x))^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f^{(n-k)}(x)g^k(x).$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ is $(f(x)g(x))^{(n)}(0)/n!$.

Comment: I think you're missing an addition sign.

Comment: What sign is missing?

Comment: I misread you derivatives as powers, so I thought you were studying the binomial theorem rather than the generalized product rule.

Answer (score 1):

Concluding my attempt

Let $S=1+x+2x^2+3x^3+...+nx^n$

$xS=x+x^2+2x^3+3x^4+...+nx^{n+1}$

$(1-x)S=1+x+x^2+x^3+....+x^n-nx^{n+1}-x=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}-nx^{n+1}-x$

$S=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{1-x+x^2}{(1-x)^2}$. (Ignoring terms which have powers of x greater than $x^n$)

So one can say that

coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x+2x^2+3x^3+.....+nx^n)^2$

=coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1-x+x^2)^2(1-x)^{-4}$

=coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1-2x+3x^2-2x^3+x^4)(1-x)^{-4}$

=$\binom{n+3}{3}-2\binom{n+2}{3}+3\binom{n+1}{3}-2\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n-1}{3}$

=$\frac{n^3+11n}{6}$.

which is too long.